# Poner un función dentro de un comando de discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

mi duda es la siguiente. Tengo una función que se repetirá en cada comando que cree y me gustaría crear una función global para no tener que repetir código repetidamente.

La idea es la siguiente, esta función estaría al comienzo del script

```py
class sorienrot:
    global checkid
    def checkid():
        serverid = ctx.guild.id
        with open("servers.json") as f:
            data = json.load(f)
        total = len(data['servidores'])
        for X in range(total):
            n = data['servidores'][X]['id']
            if n == serverid:
                if data['servidores'][X]['pagado'] == "no":
                    ctx.send("Herramienta no disponible, habla con tu administrador")
                    return
```

Y luego lo metería dentro de un comando, pero al hacerlo pasa lo siguiente:

```py
@bot.command()
async def test(ctx):
    checkid()
    print("El script continua")
```

Salida del comando:

```
Ignoring exception in command test:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/discord/.local/share/virtualenvs/botdiscordpy-ZCBYebRx/lib/python3.9/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/discord/botdiscordpy/src/index.py", line 320, in test
    checkid()
  File "/home/discord/botdiscordpy/src/index.py", line 73, in checkid
    serverid = ctx.guild.id
NameError: name 'ctx' is not defined

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/discord/.local/share/virtualenvs/botdiscordpy-ZCBYebRx/lib/python3.9/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 939, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "/home/discord/.local/share/virtualenvs/botdiscordpy-ZCBYebRx/lib/python3.9/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 863, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "/home/discord/.local/share/virtualenvs/botdiscordpy-ZCBYebRx/lib/python3.9/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: NameError: name 'ctx' is not defined
```

Como podría hacer para reconociera el código de la función del comando y reconociera el ctx y demás opciones que pueda dar el discord.py. Es decir como si formara parte del mismo comando.

Ante todo, pido disculpas por mi forma de explicarlo, ya que posiblemente no sea la mejor.

Una curiosidad mas, he intentado crear una lista para @commands.has_any_role, pero no se si es posible, ya que intentado , hacerlo de varias formas , pero no reconoce los roles.

E intentado con:

```
roles = [111111111, 11111, 1111111]
roles = (111111111, 11111, 1111111)
```

No da error, pero no detecta los roles y salta que no tienes permiso

```
@commands.has_any_role(roles)
```

Comment: creo que lo ideal sería crear un decorador

Comment: Ha y el error se debe a que la variable `ctx` no existe en el contexto de la función `checkid` una opción sería pasarla como parámetro